# Saving datasets created in a forloop to multiple files

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, dataset, saving-data

I have URLs (for web scraping) and municipality name stored in this list:

`muni = [("https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/filettino-comune-fr/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo", "filettino"),  ("https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/partanna-comune-tp/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo","partanna"), ("https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/fragneto-labate-comune-bn/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo", "fragneto-labate") ]`

I am trying to create different datasets for different municipalities. For example, data scraped from the first URL would be: `filettinodak.csv`.
I am using the following code right now:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
import random

os.chdir(r"/Users/aartimalik/Dropbox/data")

muni = [("https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/filettino-comune-fr/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo", "filettino"), 
("https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/partanna-comune-tp/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo","partanna"),
("https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/fragneto-labate-comune-bn/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo", "fragneto-labate")
]

for m in muni[1]:
    URL = m
    r = requests.get(URL)
    p = re.compile("var bilancio_tree = (.*?);")
    data = p.search(r.text).group(1)
    
    data = json.loads(data)
    
    all_data = []
    
    for d in data:
        for v in d["values"]:
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                all_data.append([d["label"], "-", kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")])
                
        for c in d["children"]:
            for v in c["values"]:
                for kk, vv in v.items():
                    all_data.append(
                        [d["label"], c["label"], kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")]
                        )
                        
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["label 1", "label 2", "year", "abs", "pc"])
    
    df.to_csv(muni[2]+"dak.csv", index=False)
```

The error I am getting is: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 19, in <module> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`.

I think I am doing something wrong with the muni indexing: `muni[i]`. Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adjust your for loop a bit, it should solve your problem. The below change loops through all list entries in `muni`. Each time, it extracts the first value from each tuple into `URL` and the second tuple value into `label`.

```
for URL, label in muni:
```

And with that change, the final line in your code can become:

```
df.to_csv(label+"dak.csv", index=False)
```